# Auth handshake fails for istio secure grpc gateway

Tags: go, kubernetes, networking, grpc, istio

Setup:

- `go` server and client communicating over gRPC
- Using Istio to help with authentication/authorization
- Was able to successfully communicate with an insecure HTTP gateway
- Now, trying to set up a secure HTTPS gateway, but it doesn't seem to work. I get this error in the client side: `"transport: authentication handshake failed: EOF"`

Note:

- I Followed istio [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/) to setup a secure gateway.
- I don't own a domain, but I read somewhere that it shouldn't be an issue when setting up a secure gateway in Istio
- Deployed in Digital Ocean

**Certificates/keys generation**

```
# Root certificate and private key
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj '/O=test/CN=test.com' -keyout certs/test.com.key -out certs/test.com.crt

# Certificate and private key for matchmaker service
openssl req -out certs/matchmaker.test.com.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout certs/matchmaker.test.com.key -subj "/CN=matchmaker.test.com/O=matchmaker" 
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA certs/test.com.crt -CAkey certs/test.com.key -set_serial 0 -in certs/matchmaker.test.com.csr -out certs/matchmaker.test.com.crt
```

**Kubernetes manifests**

Create secret to include matchmaker's certificate and key:
`kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls matchmaker-creds --key=path/to/matchmaker.test.com.key --cert=path/to/matchmaker.test.com.crt`

Gateway, VirtualService, and Service manifests:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: grpc
      protocol: GRPC
    hosts:
      - "*"
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: matchmaker-creds
    hosts:
      #- "*"
      - matchmaker.test.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vservice
spec:
  gateways:
    - gateway
  hosts:
    #- "*"
    - matchmaker.test.com
  http:
  - match:
    - authority:
        exact: "matchmaker"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: matchmaker
        port:
          number: 5001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: matchmaker
spec:
  selector:
    server: matchmaker
  ports:
    - name: https # Note: must be changed to grpc if we're connecting through port 80 in the gateway
      port: 5001
```

**Server code**
The server doesn't need to include any setup for tls since the gateway uses TLS termination, so the request that is sent to `matchmaker` service should be unencrypted, right?

```
const (
    port = ":5001"
)

func main() {
    matchmakerServer, err := matchmaker.Init()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    initializer := initializer.NewInitializer()

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    mmprotos.RegisterMatchmakerServer(grpcServer, matchmakerServer)
    initprotos.RegisterInitializerServer(grpcServer, initializer)

    // Register health check
    healthService := healthcheck.NewHealthChecker()
    grpc_health_v1.RegisterHealthServer(grpcServer, healthService)

    version := os.Getenv("VERSION")

    matchmakerServer.Logger.WithField("version", version).Infof("listening on %v", lis.Addr())

    err = grpcServer.Serve(lis)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

**Client code**

```
const (
    address = "<ip-addr>:443"
    token = "<jwt-token>"
)

func main() {
    creds, err := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile("path/to/test.com.crt", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    opts := []grpc.DialOption{
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds),
        grpc.WithAuthority("matchmaker"),
        //grpc.WithBlock(),
    }

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    client := initprotos.NewInitializerClient(conn)

    md := metadata.Pairs(
        "Authorization",
        fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %v", token),
    )

    ctx := metadata.NewOutgoingContext(
        context.TODO(),
        md,
    )

    _, err = client.Connect(ctx, &initprotos.EmptyRequest{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("connect method err: %v", err)
    }
}
```

The istio proxy logs don't show anything useful when a request is sent to the istio gateway.

Comment: Apparently, my setup is fine, but the issue was in adding SAN when signing the certificate. This helped me out: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159537/259808